# React horizontal timeline is not working....(I am using Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have converted the class component to functional and used react horizontal timeline. Don't know why it's giving this output. Any help will be really appreciated. :)

Code:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import Light from '../components/Light'
import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline'

const GrandTimeline = () => {
    const VALUES = ['01/22/1998' ,  '01/25/1999', '01/22/2000' , '01/22/2001'];
    const [ initialState, changeState] = useState({
        value:  0,
      previous:0958
     });
    return (
        <Light>
         <div>
           <HorizontalTimeline
                index={initialState.value}
             indexClick={(index) => {
               changeState({ value: index, previous: initialState.value });
             }}
            values={ VALUES } /> 
        </div>
         <div className='text-center'>  
        {initialState.value}
        </div>
        </Light>
    );
}

export default GrandTimeline
```

Output of my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nelAE.png)